# Replacing two divs to the left and right of table

Tags: html

Can i add one div to the left of a table and one another to the right of it so that the table is centered between two divs?
I have tried this code but it puts the two divs under the table not beside it

```html
<table style="width:50%" border="1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div style="float: left;">Left Div</div>
<div style="float: right;">Right Div</div>
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I edited the post with the code i have tried

Comment: add a `width:24%;` to both the div styles..and see if that helps..

Comment: nothing happened, the same problem exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/bhm6vts5/)

I've changed your HTML.Below is the edited HTML. Also I've changed the style that you have given. Gave a style `float:left` to the table,left and right div.

**HTML**

```
<div style="float: left;width:24%;height:100px;background-color:red;">Left Div</div>
<table style="width:50%;float:left;" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div style="float: left;width:24%;height:100px;background-color:red;">Right Div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using al all elements as `float:left;` is the best solution.

```css
table {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
.left-div,
.right-div {
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.left-div {
  background-color: red;
}
.right-div {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-div"></div>
<table border="1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="right-div"></div>
```